# соединение числа и типа в с++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно соединить в одной сущности число и пользовательский тип. Можно даже сказать ассоциировать. Как это можно было  бы сделать (без ветвления и свича).
Спасибо.

Comment: Постарайтесь описать вопрос более развернуто, чтобы кроме вас еще кто-нибудь мог понять что вам нужно.

Comment: std::map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

Comment: Ничего не понял. Можете пример кода показать?

Comment: Так вот как раз мне и нужен пример кода. Есть идея, а нужен код. Подробнее написал бы , если бы мог.

Answer (score 1):

Ну либо так:

```cpp
struct SomeStruct {
public:
    int num;
    SomeClass some;
};
```

Либо так:

```cpp
map<int, SomeClass> some;
```

Либо так:

```cpp
vector<pair<int, SomeClass>> some;
```

Comment: Спасибо.Но это сопоставление числа и объекта, а мне бы хотелось: число с типом сопоставить. (если конечно, это возможно)

Comment: @nox2020 тогда можно использовать это: `map<int, const type_info*> some;`.  Использование: `some[123213] = &typeid(SomeStruct);`

Comment: Подумал. Не выходит теперь создать объект типа SomeStruct из some[123213].

Comment: @nox2020 в с++ так делать вроде нельзя. Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)